# How to change name in adress bar / tab SP2013

Tags: 2013

I'm running SharePoint 2013 and want to change the Name in the Adressbar/Tab of the Browser.

On the default/homesite I solved the problem by adding some Text in the SEO settings. But in all the sub sites there is the Title in the adress bar something like: Homepage - Departments or Homepage - Search.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

Greetings
Philipp

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint controls this with an ASP.Net content placeholder control in the master page. Look for `<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderId="PlaceholderPageTitle" ... />` in the master page. The page layout will generally set the title based on the title field for the page. One way to customize this is to change what is being placed in this content placeholder on the page layout your page is using. Check out [this article](http://www.topsharepoint.com/change-title-tag-on-sharepoint-sites).

Answer (score 0):

To change label in tab of the browser, you can change title of the page.
As example you can use JavaScript:
`document.title = "New title";`

Try this.
But i think that we have another way, more better

Answer (score 0):

It works now.

I solved it by adding the following in the head of my masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="Websitename | " EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty runat="server" id="ProjectProperty1" Property="Title" />
</SharePoint:PageTitle>
```

I appreciate your help.